# text disappears on Opera browser

Tags: wordpress, opera

I'm making a template based on twentytwelve in wordpress. Everything works fine on my computer, but on another one, all of the text disappears.
Both computers are with windows and use Opera 12.16, build 1860. I checked out the source code on the computer with disappeared text and it's there. Any ideas what can cause that problem?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjaD7.jpg

Comment: Could you give some link?

Comment: http://foodmarket.bg/

The website is using polylang. And I figured out that the problem appears when I switch between languages and appears only in the first one (bg-BG).